# Can the built in static resources be used when redefining a control template

Tags: wpf, xaml

In WPF if I want to redefine a controls style, in my example making a specialty button, I know I can use visual studio to extract a copy of the template for me to play with.

However when visual studio generates the button style I end up with a bunch of static resources that pop in to be defined. In my button example I get the following.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
```

In my case I want to maintain all the standard button colours.

Instead of having all these extra definitions is there any way to just point at the same resources that the standard button control uses.

Comment: You can find some colors and their resource key in the [SystemColors Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemcolors?view=windowsdesktop-8.0). If you don't override the ControlTemplate then you don't have to redefine all its state triggers. In this case use a simple Style without setting the control's Template property. What are you doing?

Comment: I am adding a few extra properties to the button for easier (and consistent reuse) I need to override the template to do this, for example some of the changes are adding an Icon (Brush) IconRotation(double) IconColour (Brush) properties so I can have nice clean definitions for icon buttons with a label (the original button content) without needing to define a stackpanel, image, contentcontrol etc) for each instance.

Comment: Thank you. Based on this information I can suggest a graceful solution where your custom button will behave as usual allowing for all usual customizations by the client code. Still, it gives you the author enough control over the internal layout - without overriding the default visual state behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The `Button` is a `ContentControl`. As such you don't have to override the `ControlTemplate` in order to change the layout. Overriding the `ControlTemplate` generally makes more sense if you want to change the visual state behavior. But this you don't want to. You want to keep the original visual behavior.

Because the `Button` is a `ContentControl`, all you have to do is to define a `DataTemplate` for the `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` property. That's the main idea. But to allow the user of your control to define his own `Button.ContentTemplate` for the `Button.Content` value, we must set our content template explicitly on the button's internal `ContentPresenter` and delegate the client's `Button.ContentTemplate` to our new content host that we define inside the content template.
In other words, our `DataTemplate` is the real content template and is set *internally* by accessing the button'S `ContentPresenter` and not implicitly via the `Button.ContentTemplate` property. Our content template also presents the original `Button.Content` value, which requires you to delegate the `Button.Content` property to a dedicated content host in our content template. In addition, we also have to delegate the `Button.ContentTemplate` property to still allow the client to customize the `Button.Content` value.

The client of the custom `Button` control won't recognize any difference in usage and behavior. that's the key.
The advantage is that the client can still define complex content definitions and even overide the default `ControlTemplate`. As long the `ContentTemplate` contains a `ContentPresenter`, our `AdvancedButton` will continue to work.
Optionally, if you want the client to allow overriding the `ControlTemplate` in a breaking way i.e. allowing him to completely redefine the layout, you could add a e.g. `IsOverridingContentAllowed` property.

The following example shows how you can implement a custom `AdvancedButton` which provides it own layout without breaking the default usage and behavior and the visual state effects of the original `Button`.

**App.xaml**
The `DataTemplate` that will be applied to the button's internal `ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate` property.

If you don't want to add the `DataTemplate` to the application's resource dictionary e.g., because you want to ship your control with a library, then you can add it to any XAML `ResourceDictionary` and embed this resource file into the DLL (build action). Then retrieve the resource with the help of the `ResourceManager`.

```xml
<Application>
  <Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="{x:Static AdvancedButton.DefaultContentTemplateKey}">
      <StackPanel>

        <!-- Icon host -->
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:AdvancedButton}, Path=Icon}" />
          
        <!-- 
             Content host. 
             To preserve the original behavior of the Button.ContentTemplate, 
             we have to delegate Button.ContentTemplate value to the actual content host.
             Otherwise, because this current template is already applied to 
             the original ContentPresenter of the Button, 
             setting Button.ContentTemplate externally would override/remove 
             this current DataTemplate.

             Because we intentionally broke the link of the button's 
             ContentPresenter to the AdvancedButton (ContentPresenter host) 
             we have to explicitly wire the original properties 
             ContentTemplateSelector and ContentStringFormat to the new content host. 
             If we did not do this, the behavior would be completely broken 
             and setting those content related properties would have no effect.
        -->
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                        ContentTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:AdvancedButton}, Path=ContentTemplate}"
                        ContentTemplateSelector="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:AdvancedButton}, Path=ContentTemplateSelector}"
                        ContentStringFormat="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:AdvancedButton}, Path=ContentStringFormat}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**AdvancedButton.cs**

```cs
public class AdvancedButton : Button
{
  public static ResourceKey DefaultContentTemplateKey = new DataTemplateKey();

  public object Icon
  {
    get => (object)GetValue(IconProperty);
    set => SetValue(IconProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Icon",
    typeof(object),
    typeof(AdvancedButton),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public DataTemplate DefaultContentTemplate
  {
    get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(DefaultContentTemplateProperty);
    private set => SetValue(DefaultContentTemplatePropertyKey, value);
  } 

  private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey DefaultContentTemplatePropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
    "DefaultContentTemplate",
    typeof(DataTemplate),
    typeof(AdvancedButton),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultContentTemplateProperty = DefaultContentTemplatePropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

  protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
  {
    ContentPresenter cp;
    base.OnInitialized(e);
    if (TryFindResource(AdvancedButton.DefaultContentTemplateKey) is DataTemplate defaultContentTemplate)
    {
      this.DefaultContentTemplate = defaultContentTemplate;
    }
  }

  public override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    if (TryFindChild(this, out ContentPresenter? contentPresenter))
    {
      // Setting the ContentPresenter!.ContentTemplate property directly
      // will break the default binding between the ContentPresenter
      // and its host (the button and its ContentTemplate property).
      // We explicitly want to break that link because we have to manuall apply
      // our default DataTemplate instead and then delegate the button's ContentTemplate value
      // to the ContentControl inside the default template.
      // Delegation happens via data binding in the default DataTemplate.
      // The goal is to allow the button to behave as expected to the client code.
      // This way the Button.ContentTemplate will behave as expected:
      // it will (appear to) correctly template the Button.Content value.
      contentPresenter!.ContentTemplate = this.DefaultContentTemplate;
    }
  }

  private bool TryFindChild<TChild>(DependencyObject parent, out TChild? child) where TChild : DependencyObject
  {
    child = parent as TChild;
    if (child is not null)
    {
      return true;
    }

    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int childIndex = 0; childIndex < childrenCount; childIndex++)
    {
      DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);
      child = childElement as TChild;
      if (child is not null || TryFindChild(childElement, out child))
      {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
  <AdvancedButton Content="Label text" 
                  Icon="Set icon resource here" />

  <!-- Providing a content template won't break the new AdvancedButton layout -->
  <AdvancedButton Content="Label text" 
                  Icon="Set icon resource here">
    <AdvancedButton.ContentTemplate>

      <!-- 
           As commonly expected, this DataTemplate will only affect 
           the value of the Button.Content property. 
           But it will not override or default content template.
      -->
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                   FontSize="48"
                   Foreground="Orange" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </AdvancedButton.ContentTemplate>
  </AdvancedButton>
</Window>
```